# Index/Match with multiple possible answers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There's a question about how to return some info in Excel, [COUNTIFS for VLOOKUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837544/countifs-for-vlookup). from @THATNewbie.

Here's a quick summary:

They have this table:

```
Report Name        User Name      Report Category
Report 1           John Smith     Sales
Report 1           Jack Black     Sales
Report 1           Connie Rae     Sales
Report 1           Brain Bonds    Sales
Report 2           John Smith     Sales
Report 2           Connie Rae     Sales
Report 3           Jack Black     Inventory
```

And they would like to return the "Report Name" based on User Name and Report Category.

My first thought was just to use Index/Match (as an Array)...however, I realize that if I use "John Smith" and "Sales" to look up the Report Name, there's two possible outcomes: `Report 1` and `Report 2`.  Index/Match will always return `Report1` (or whatever comes first, going down that column).

My question is: Is there a way to write the Index/Match formula to check if it's already found `Report1` and therefore to go to the next match (`Report2`)?

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33n2U.jpg) to help visualize. As you can see, the Index/Match correctly finds `Report1` in C12, but also in C13.  Can you have the formula "look above" and if it's the answer that it WOULD return, to skip that and look for the next?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you add your current function that always gives the first

Comment: I can show you the steps I use to solve this if you like; however, it doesn't include Index/Match.

Comment: @rwilson - I see your solution in the other thread, thanks for that!

Comment: Yeah, that was one nasty formula due to how the table was shaped and the desired output. This question you have here is a more reasonable one  though and is a situation that I see come up often when buidlng array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
=INDEX(Report_Name,MATCH(The_User&":"&The_Category,User_Name&":"&Report_Category,0))
```

The idea is to concatenate user name and report category into a single search item. (I added a colon char as a delimiter; this was optional and could possibly be omitted.) Then use MATCH to get the index of the matching item, and INDEX to convert the index to a specific report.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hm, it only shows `Report1` when I look for "John Smith" and "Sales" twice (as in the screenshot).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Are your trying to find all matches, the last match, the first match, or something else?

Comment: ah, sorry if I wasn't clear.  I'm trying to find all matches.  So, in [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/QWJHKmQ.jpg), the first entry (that I'm showing the formula for) returns "Report1".  I want that second one to show "Report2".  (Somehow know that "Report1" has been returned already, so to look for the next occurrence in the table).

Comment: Got it. Excel's TABLE functionality will do that. (LIST in older versions of Excel). TABLEs are an easy way to filter data sets. If you want similar functionality from INDEX/MATCH, you could output Index1 from the first match to a cell, then use Index1 as an offset from the top of the list to get a new starting point for MATCH to get Index2, and so forth. It seems kind of messy, but should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way (to my knowledge) to do this. You will have to add some sort of unique identifier to each row, or a value that helps define it uniquely. For example, you could add a new column with this function

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2, "=" & $B2, $C$2:$C2, "=" & $C2)
```

What this will do is count the total number times that that specific grouping has shown up, and effectively act as a pseudo ID for it. Then you can add that item to your Index/Match

Then in the second table you showed in the image, you just repeat the count function in the match, so you will have

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8, MATCH(1, (A12 = $B$2:$B$8) * (B12 = $C$2:$C$8) * (COUNTIFS($A$12:$A12, "=" & $A2, $B$2:$B2, "=" & $B2) = $D$2:$D8), 0))
```

This is an array entered forumla

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Is there a way to write the Index/Match formula to
>   check if it's already found Report1 and therefore to go to the next
>   match (Report2)?

Yes, but a simpler way it can be done is using index & small.

**Index & small**

Need to CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Copy down for remaining rows.

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$16,SMALL(IF(A19=$B$2:$B$16,IF(B19=$C$2:$C$16,ROW($B$2:$B$16)-ROW($B$2)+1),""),ROW(B2)-1))}
```

Where A19 & B19 contain cells for search criteria.

**Using Index & Match;**

This could possibly be simplified but shows the steps.

Add another column alongside the search criteria area & change the formulas as below.

Need to CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Column C (Report Name);

Following for the first row or search criteria item only

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(A21&B21,$B$2:$B$16&$C$2:$C$16,0)+ROW(A2)-1)}
```

Copy following down for the remaining rows items.

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$A$16,MATCH(A22&B22,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",E22,":","B16"))&INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C",E22,":","C16")),0)+ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",E22)))-1,1)}
```

Column E - helper column. Helper column returns the start of the next row.

First row item is N/A.

Following for 2nd or search criteria item only.

```
{=MATCH(A22&B22,$B$2:$B$16&$C$2:$C$16,0)+ROW(A2)}
```

Following copy down for remaining rows.

```
{=MATCH(A23&B23,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",E22,":","B16"))&INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("C",E22,":","C16")),0)+ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("F",E22)))}
```

This however does assume the search criteria is the same, unlike the other question referred to. If search criteria is different or more complex refer to 
[COUNTIFS for VLOOKUP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837544/countifs-for-vlookup/31845011#31845011)